# How to ban IPs at gateway with fail2ban on multiple backend servers?

Tags: remote, nftables, fail2ban

I have configured fail2ban successfully on multiple backend servers on my network and it's all ok -- except that I would like a ban originating from eg email to be banned not just for email but all services.

At present, the ban action is local, so the server on which the bad thing was noticed gets protected, but none of the others. I did contemplate simply using 'ssh' to execute the 'nft' action on the gateway, but this would fail when/if the 'unban' happened.

What I think I want is the "action" part of fail2ban on the gateway, keeping track of ban requests, timeouts and similar actions, and actioning it with nftables, while the multiple servers with logs pass all such requests to it?

Does this make sense? What would the normal way to deal with this be?

[The gateway is configured with shorewall, and there are about 6 other servers involved, some of which are being port-forwarded to by the gateway.]

Comment: The "normal way" of dealing with this would be to have all your servers behind a single firewall and use that, instead of making every server do the firewall job.